# Wep th400 thermal printer + Rasberry

Tags: raspberrypi

I have a Wep th400 thermal printer  that is in good condition, it works in Windows and Ubuntu 19 in 32 + 64 bit,

but not with my fresh installation of  Ubuntu 19.10 32 bit Raspberry Version (https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi).

The printer is recognized and configured, but not printing, saying about any job:  Stopped - Filter failed .

Solution# for this  in  Ubuntu 19 in 32 + 64 bit 
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386
sudo apt-get install libcups2:i386
But I am not able to run this command in raspberry Ubuntu Version,

Also I noticed that while Installing Raspberry Ubuntu 64bit 19.10 server, It has issues with USB, can't login on first boot as keyboard/mouse won't work.

Please suggest me

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19 (nor Ubuntu Core 19), nor was there a Ubuntu 19.04 in 32bit/x86/i386 (http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.04/) so please clarify (or check) your question.  `libcupsimage2` is available for : amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x in 19.10

Comment: How to install 32 bit cups libraries in raspberry Ubuntu?https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2238079

Comment: getting error : e: unable to locate package libcupsimage2:i386